# "TypeError: curve is not a function. (In 'curve(buffer = path())', 'curve' is undefined)" in d3.js.v4

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js

I am working through a d3.js Linkedin Learning course, creating graphs and interpolating them by type. Link to course video [here](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/d3-js-essential-training-for-data-scientists/introducing-groups?u=76958498). I keep getting the above error, and I think it has to do with the fact that the videos are from 2016 and use v4 of d3.js, but I have no idea how to fix it. I found an answer to this problem [on GitHub here](https://github.com/metricsgraphics/metrics-graphics/issues/686) but I don't understand it. If someone could ELI5 I would really appreciate it! Thanks.

```js
var dataArray = [{
  x: 6,
  y: 8
}, {
  x: 9,
  y: 2
}, {
  x: 12,
  y: 19
}, {
  x: 19,
  y: 21
}, {
  x: 23,
  y: 43
}];

var interpolateTypes = [d3.curveLinear, d3.curveNeutral, d3.curveStep, d3.curveBasis, d3.curveBundle, d3.curveCardinal];

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('height', '100%').attr('width', '100%');


for (var p = 0; p < 6; p++) {

  var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) {
      return d.x * 6;
    })
    .y(function(d, i) {
      return d.y * 4;
    })
    .curve(interpolateTypes[p]);

  var shiftX = p * 250;
  var shiftY = 0;

  var chartGroup = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + shiftX + ', 0)');

  chartGroup.append('path')
    .attr('d', line(dataArray))
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('fill', 'none');

  chartGroup.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('class', function(d, i) {
      return 'grp' + i;
    })
    .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
      return d.x * 6;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
      return d.y * 4;
    })
    .attr('r', '2');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add the code that gives you the error, preferably in a [mre]. Can be as a snippet, a jsfiddle, or a codepen. It will help you get better answers

Comment: @RubenHelsloot I added the code into my question- I guess it's not as minimal as possible but since it's such a short section I figured I'd put the whole thing. this section seems to be the trigger:

   `var line = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d,i){ return d.x*6; })
                    .y(function(d,i){ return d.y*4; })
                    .curve(interpolateTypes[p]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `d3.curveNatural`, not `d3.curveNeutral`. Because `curveNeutral` doesn't exist, it returned `undefined`.

```js
var dataArray = [{
  x: 6,
  y: 8
}, {
  x: 9,
  y: 2
}, {
  x: 12,
  y: 19
}, {
  x: 19,
  y: 21
}, {
  x: 23,
  y: 43
}];

var interpolateTypes = [d3.curveLinear, d3.curveNatural, d3.curveStep, d3.curveBasis, d3.curveBundle, d3.curveCardinal];

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('height', '100%').attr('width', '100%');

var ln

for (var p = 0; p < interpolateTypes.length; p++) {
  var line = d3.line()
    .curve(interpolateTypes[p])
    .x(function(d, i) {
      return d.x * 6;
    })
    .y(function(d, i) {
      return d.y * 4;
    });

  var shiftX = p * 250;
  var shiftY = 0;

  var chartGroup = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + shiftX + ', 0)');

  chartGroup.append('path')
    .attr('d', line(dataArray))
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('fill', 'none');

  chartGroup.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('class', function(d, i) {
      return 'grp' + i;
    })
    .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
      return d.x * 6;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
      return d.y * 4;
    })
    .attr('r', '2');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for this! I might have misunderstood the instructor's accent and never noticed. It works perfectly now.